# Как присваивать переменным значения, состоящие из нескольких строк?

Tags: python

Функция **input()** позволяет присвоить значение переменной из одной строки, а как добавлять значения в переменную через input которые состоят из множества строк?

Например мне нужно сравнить между собой 2 массива данных:

```
купить слона
купить синего слона
цены на слонов
...
и таких строк сотни
```

и

```
слоны в рассрочку
слоны дисконт
слоны оптом
...
и таких тоже сотни
```

**как быстро сформировать 2 списка из этих значений, чтобы получить на выходе:**

```
a = ['купить слона', 'купить синего слона', 'цены на слонов', ... ]
b = ['слоны в рассрочку', 'слоны дисконт', 'слоны оптом', ... ]
```

**Дополнено:**

Файл с массивами данных в формате txt, по одному значению на строчке, разделены переводом строки (без запятых).

Comment: Так вам нужно считать несколько строк в одну переменную или все же сравнить 2 массива строк?

Comment: Можете сделать *input().split(",")* и вводить эти строчки через запятую, в итоге получите 1 массив строк

Comment: @Dareten мне нужно преобразовать список из строк в переменную со списком из значений в этом списке, то есть например в текстарею я ввожу строки в столбик, а на выходе получаю переменную где каждая строчка эта значение этой переменной.

Comment: @Dareten неправильно был отформатирован вопрос, поправил, теперь наверно стало понятней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно я не совсем понял, но как то так:

```
result = []
count = 0
while count < 100:
    a = input('Введите строку: ')
    result.append(a)
    count +=1
    print(result)
```

Эта функция позволит взять файл и получить из него массив по разделителю:

```
def SplitFIle(filelink, razdelitel):
    file = open(filelink, 'r') #откроем файл на чтение
    text = file.read() #возьмем от туда текст
    file.close #закроем файл
    text = text.split(razdelitel) #разобьем по разделителю
    return (text) #вернем массив данных
list1 = SplitFIle('somefile.txt', '\n') #указали ссылку на файл и разделителель (в данном случае - перенос строки)
print(list1)
```

Comment: спасибо, метод работает, но приходится вводить данные по одному значению на строку, а мне нужно сотни строк за раз добавить.

Comment: а зачем вам input вообще тогда? input - это ручной ввод с клавиатуры. если у вас хранятся данные в текстовом файле, то вы можете взять их и разбить по разделителю через split(',') - создастся массив строк

Comment: объясните в каком виде и где хранятся ваши данные, дополнив вопрос. Я тогда смогу показать рабочий пример.

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: Недостаточно дополнили. Как именно хранение происходит? Все элементы для одного массива хранятся в одном отдельном файле? Элементы разделены через запятую в этом файле? Файл в формате txt?

Comment: Файл в формате txt, по одному значению на строчке, разделены переводом строки (без запятых), просто список запросов в столбик. 2 файла с запросами.

Comment: спасибо за ответ и особенно за комментарии к каждой строчке, всё работает

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = []
while True:
    line = input()
    if line:
        lines.append(line)
    else:
        break
print(lines)
```

Таким образом вы сможете записывать строки в `list`, пока они не кончатся.

Answer (score 0):

Если количество строк неизвестно, то можно сделать вот так:

```
import sys
array = sys.stdin.read().split("\n")
```

Учитывайте что для завершения ввода нужно будет отправить EOF(Ctrl + D в большинстве случаев)